# Not Connect modbus TCP

Tags: java, android, tcp, modbus

I have a problem with the connection through ethernet modbus tcp.
I insert in to AndroidManifest the permission:
  
And i create task or connecting and reading Modbus.
I use jamod library.

When I start the application gives me a connection failed error.

This my code that i use:

```
class Task implements Runnable {

    @
    Override

    public void run() {

        try {
            ReadMultipleRegistersResponse result = null;

            //Read And Write Register Sample
            int port = Modbus.DEFAULT_PORT;
            String refe = "4000"; //HEX Address
            int ref = Integer.parseInt(refe, 16); //Hex to int          
            int count = 98; //the number Address to read
            int SlaveAddr = 1;
            String astr = "192.168.0.18"; //Modbus Device                  

            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(astr);
            TCPMasterConnection con = new TCPMasterConnection(addr);
            ModbusTCPTransaction trans = null; //the transaction


            //1.Prepare the request
            /************************************/
            ReadMultipleRegistersRequest Rreq = new ReadMultipleRegistersRequest(ref, count);
            ReadMultipleRegistersResponse Rres = new ReadMultipleRegistersResponse();

            Rreq.setUnitID(SlaveAddr); //set Slave Address  
            Rres.setUnitID(SlaveAddr); //set Slave Address

            //2. Open the connection
            con.setPort(port);

            con.connect();

            con.setTimeout(2500);

            //3. Start Transaction
            trans = new ModbusTCPTransaction(con);
            trans.setRetries(5);

            trans.setReconnecting(true);
            trans.setRequest(Rreq);
            trans.execute();

            /*Print Response*/
            Rres = (ReadMultipleRegistersResponse) trans.getResponse();
        } catch (ModbusSlaveException me) {

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Where am I doing wrong ?

Comment: That ip address is of?

Comment: Default port for Modbus is 502. On Linux the port will be blocked by the firewall. I suspect on Android the port may also be blocked by default.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps

1. Check your slave is working
2. Check your device of slave that have the same network with the master
3. Check your port setting of security (default 502)